# Can I pass @ARGV and options to a perl script invoked via do?

Tags: perl

I have a script which processes `@ARGV` and options (via [Getopt::Long::Descriptive](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long::Descriptive)).

Now, I would also like to call that same script from another perl program, and pass variables to it.

One solution is to use `system`, and build the arguments passed accordingly like so:

```
system("perl my_script.pl", qw/--foo bar --baz 2/);
```

My question is: can I obtain the same result by calling the script via `do`?

I'm trying to do this because the script would run inside a [Minion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minion) job queue so I would avoid spawning off a perl instance every time - that often causes out-of-memory issues.

Comment: Afaik no, but you can `open my $fh, "-|", qw(executable, ..args )` and read output via `$fh` handle.

Comment: Why do you want to use `do`? That's not a common requirement.

Comment: @briandfoy - I'm trying to use the same script(s) that I use on the command line - which are based on GetOpt::Long::Descriptive - also as Minion (Mojolicious job queue) tasks without having to rewrite the whole thing(s). Bad idea?

Comment: Yes, it's a bad idea. What you `do` stomps all over whatever your program is doing. Why was `system` inadequate?

Comment: @briandfoy `system` spawns off a perl instance with every script - that sometimes causes OOM. I was thinking `do` would save some overhead. BTW - both the Getopt script and the Minion server are stuff I write - don't know if that helps. I was hoping/thinking to achieve something similar to modulinos - one thing that does two jobs

Comment: all of these clarifications are the sort of information that would be good in the question.

Comment: @briandfoy - edited. Sometimes I got flaḱ or caused confusion for too much context, sometimes too little. Thanks for the advice though - I'll try harder next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rajashekar's answer is correct, but I would also add you can set args for the child script in a `local` block so that the child doesn't need to corrupt `@ARGV` in the parent.

```
{
    local @ARGV = ("--foo","bar","--baz",$ARGV[3]);
    do 'my_script.pl';
}
# previous @ARGV restored at end of block
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `@ARGV` yourself and then evaluate the script file.

This will work

```
@ARGV = qw(--foo --bar).
do $script_file;
```

Since `@ARGV` is a global variable it is available inside `do` too. But if you want to access any local variables you have defined, then you can to use:

```
eval `cat $script_file`;
```

EDIT: I had mistakenly assumed that `@ARGV` will not be accessible within `do`.